# Android - How to change system's Date & Time through third party application programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I want to change android system's date and time through third party application programmatically. If I change it from any application it should affect system's date and time.It should not open system's setting application, changes should be made only from my application.

Comment: You need `android.permission.SET_TIME` .This permission has the protectionLevel of `signatureOrSystem` . So if you can gain this permission either because you rooted your phone or built and signed your own platform image then you can change the date and time, just like changing time zone.

Answer (score 0):

The user application does not have permission to change the device time.
we can only redirect the user to date time activity of system

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS));
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to link them directly to the time setting (which would save them one more click).

To do it by code you need to create admin level app.

Comment: How can I create admin level app? or what are the requirements to create admin level app?

Comment: if you create admin level app than you need to singed app by OEM like samsung, sony, htc.

Comment: use this link to create admin level app https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Comment: Admin level app can change password or encrypt the storage of a client application, but how it will change systems date and time?

Comment: you can use reflection to get value and set value